# Can we encode URL in .xsl file?

Tags: xslt, urlencode

Can we encode URL in .xsl file? If yes, then how we can do that?
I have used below code:

```
Prompt type="label" pointer="abc.asp?mynumber={my-number}&amp;myname={my-name}"
```

It works fine for other name, but if name contains `&`, then it is breaking.
Could someone help me to solve it?

Comment: I don't see any XSLT code in your question, nor it is clear which kind of output (plain text or HTML or XML) you want to create, nor which exact URL you want to create. There are some functions in the XPath library, see https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/ containing `encode-for-uri` https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-encode-for-uri or `escape-html-uri` https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-escape-html-uri that might help, depending on your exact needs.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience browsers may treat & and `&amp;` the same you're likely to end up with a link that doesn't work correctly anyway.

If you're not certain of what the my-name node might contain then it might be better to create a variable from it first. Then you can make sure that any ampersands are removed first.

Actually, the first thing you should try is to agree that the my-name node never contains an ampersand in the first place. But I know that sort  of request is often ignored so there is a solution.

If you use a variable, you can include a find and replace to remove/replace the &. There isn't a function for this in xslt 1 but you can use the translate function instead

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>
  <xsl:template match="/Test">

  <xsl:variable name="safe-name" select="translate(my-name, '&amp;', '|')"/>

    MyName - <xsl:value-of select="$safe-name"/>

  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I've given this a quick test and it works with several & in the node (you can never be too careful). Hope that helps